# typescript classes from GET vs POST

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure how to phrase the title, which is why it's so hard to search, but I have the following problem:

Let say I have something like this used to display data on the front end:

```
class User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

class Comment {
    id: number;
    text: string;
    user: User
}
```

But to submit a comment to the back end, I would need to send:

```
{
    text: 'some text',
    user: 123
}
```

So I can't just create a new Comment instance, how can this be handled? Do I need two classes, one for incoming comment and one for outgoing? Do I need to manually create a javascript object, something like:

```
let c = {
    text: 'some text',
    user: xxx.user.id
}
```

It doesn't seem like a great approach for large nested objects and such, any insight is appreciated, I'm fairly new to TS (coming from JS / node).

Comment: Those are different independent types: `Comment` and `CommentPostRequest`

Answer (score 0):

lazy approach

```
interface IComment {
    id: number;
    text: string;
    user: User | number;
}
```

Comment: That's one option I considered, but is there a standard or best practice / better way?